# Unable to run update windows remotely via power shell

Tags: azure

Unable to run windows update remotely via powershell

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force

Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -Force

Import-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate

Install-WindowsUpdate -KBArticleID KB890830,KB2267602 -Confirm:$false -AutoReboot

Error Message :

Install-Module : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\1.1.5\Downloads\s
cript4.ps1:3 char:1

- Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -Force
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-Module:String) [], Comm 
  andNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Windows Management Framework is missing at the target server. Please install it and try again

[Windows Management Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616)

Thanks,
Manu